# Randomizing selection in R

Tags: r, data

I am trying to create a comparison group. So far this group contains 45 data points and I need to populate the remaining 55 (for a total of 100 data points).

These remaining 55 need to be a randomized selection supplied from a larger data set. Any recommendations for R code that would create a randomization loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a sample with 55 record from the larger data-set that you have.

```
 sample <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), 55, replace=FALSE),]
```

If you want to make a reproducible example of the sample, you need to `set seed` like this:

```
 set.seed(57)
 sample <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), 55, replace=FALSE),]
```

So later you can use the same seed for getting the same result.

p.s. `replace=FALSE` means that each record after that has been picked from the `df` to be included in the sample, will be excluded from the `df` and it will not be chosen multiple times.

Comment: thank you - is there any additional way to ensure that the random 55 data points that are pulled are matched for a certain variable with the 45 data points that already exist? For example, say Im trying to match a list of participants on years of education - is there a way to randomize the selection of the 55 so that they match with the existing 45 data points?

Comment: @timemachinez What do you mean by "match"? Do you want 55-records to have same average or same value for "years of education" as the other 45-ones?

Comment: Id like them to be the same average, sorry for lack of clarification

Comment: @timemachinez Let me think about. But that's not random sampling since you are enforcing a condition.